# Lets Encrypt subdomain not secure

Tags: certbot

I had an LetsEncrypt SSL certificate for my domain (both domain.com and www.domain.com). Now, I wanted to add workflow.domain.com to the certificate. I tried using the expand option of the certbot with the command below:

```
certbot -d domain.com -d www.domain.com -d workflow.domain.com --expand
```

Certbot returned a success response. However, the browser was still showing insecure...

So, I have revoked my certificates to start clean.

I ran the certbot with `certbot --apache`. It showed my 3 options correctly, so I choose all 3 to be included in the certificate.

The certbot returns without errors, though the browser keeps showing me insecure on `workflow.domain.com`?

The output of `certbot certificates` is as shown below:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: domain.com
    Domains: domain.com workflow.domain.com www.domain.com
    Expiry Date: 2019-12-20 15:05:24+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note, the other 2 domains (domain.com and www.domain.com) show as secure

The virtual host config for the subdomain is shown below:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName workflow.domain.com

        serverAdmin info@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/Domain/Workflow

        <Directory /var/www/Domain/Workflow>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

AddType application/x-font-ttf                  ttc ttf
AddType application/x-font-otf                  otf
AddType application/font-woff                   woff
AddType application/font-woff2                  woff2
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject           eot
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the message saying the domain is not secure telling you about the cause of the problem? Does it say it's because the name is not matching, or something else?

Comment: I have no idea? Where can I check those messages? All I see is 'not secure' in the browser. Or the padlock (striped)

Comment: You can sooner or later find something like see certificate in the menus you get after clicking on the broken padlock.

Comment: @g_bor, it unfortunately is not showing any information about the SSL certificate because it seems that the browsers don't recognise any certificate being present for the subdomain at all. As stated, the certificates works but not for the subdomain and I can't figure out what's the problem. I used the certbot to add the domain (even through a new certificate after revoking the old ones...)

Comment: Could you have a look at the webserver configuration associated with the new subdomain? It seems possbile that somehow the virtualhost is not picked up by certbot...

Comment: @g_bor I have checked the virtual host file for the subdomain in `/etc/apache2/sites-enables/...`. This does include the certificate as expected (`SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`) with both the correct paths. As showed in the original question. The subdomain is part of the Domains for the certificate, so I'm confused what I did wrong here...

Comment: It still seems that for some reason apache did not pick up the certificate, could you edit the question to include the relevant vhost configuration.

Comment: Also there are some online ssl checkers, could you try one and tell us what it says about the issue?

Comment: @g_bor I have edited the question and added the virtual host configuration of the subdomain

Comment: @g_bor, I have tested the certificate using ssllabs website. I enter workflow.domain.com. It shows in the response for subject domain.com and tells the certificate is great (A-classification). However, I doubt or this checked the actual subdomain?

Comment: Are you checking your site security with an SNI enabled client? It might happen that the wrong certificate is returned in that case. You might be able to get a *.domain.com wildcard certificate instead, which would work with clients without sni support. I am not sure what certificate certbot gives for a command like that. I might be wrong here.

Comment: @g_bor I have no idea about SNI. Both Safari and Firefox tell me the site is http instead of https. But I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.. All settings and config files seem correct

Comment: How do you try to access your site? Are you simply typing the url into the title bar of the browser? If yes, then from the vhost configuration I see that the rewrites are commented, so you do not get an automaitc redirect to the https site. Could you check if the problem persists if you try https:// workflow.domain.com?

Comment: Wow... that’s the problem! Using explicitly https works. However, certbot is set to redirect to https... how can I modify this is the vhost since certbot doesn’t seem to redirect for the subdomain. Many thanks for your time and solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be missing redirect to https. The rewrite code is commented on the subdomain. You can add these lines to you vhost configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = workflow.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Please consider editing the question, so that it reflects the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add this flag to the certbot service in my docker-compose.yml file: (***--expand -d someone.me,www.someone.me,bo.someone.me***)

```
command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email someone.someone@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal --expand -d someone.me,www.someone.me,bo.someone.me
```